# Is there a better way to generate i18n links to resources with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

What is the best way to generate links to resources so that the text displayed takes into consideration i18n shenanigans?

What I am currently doing:

```
<%= link_to t("links.menu.foos"), foos_path %>
```

So that I get a link that looks like `<a href='/foos'>Foos</a>`

But this seems silly - my model (Foo) already has a name. It just feels like there should be an easier way like:

```
<%= link_to Foo, foos_path %>
```

And in my en.yml:

```
activemodel:
  models:
    foo
      name:
        one: Foo
        other: Foos
```

Answer (score 1):

With the [the standard way to translate ActiveRecord models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      foo: Foo
```

you can use [ActiveModel::Name#human](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Name.html#method-i-human):

```
link_to Foo.model_name.human, foos_path
```

I don't know if your `en.yml` syntax with `one` and `others` is a Rails standard and if `ActiveModel::Name#human` can make use of it. I've tried it in a small application but without success.

Comment: ```@florent2``` thanks for taking the time. Yeah I was hoping for something a little more automagic given that ActiveRecord knows the name of my resource and there is a good chance that when I create a href to my resource the name of the resource will also be the name of the link.